# java.awt.HeadlessException while using Toolkit class to get screen size

Tags: java

While I am trying to get the screen size (width and height) of the monitor using Toolkit class, I always get an exception: java.awt.HeadlessExcetion.
It's happening while I am running my code from MAC terminal but it's running perfectly while I am running it from eclipse.

Why is this happening? Will anyone explain it please?

Comment: It might be useful if you post your entire stack trace.

Comment: How you run it? What flags you pass? HeadlessException is actualy mean that host have no video.

Comment: I ran my project from MAC terminal without using any flags. @talex